# Плохое качество при записи и кропе в ффмпег

Tags: python, видео, ffmpeg

[Ничего из этой статьи не помогло](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33378548/ffmpeg-crop-a-video-without-losing-the-quality)

Проблема в том, что видео изначально записывается в плохом качестве и при кропе оно становится еще хуже
команды, которую использую сейчас:

**Запись:** `ffmpeg -f gdigrab -i desktop -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -t 30 video1.mp4`

**Кроп:** `ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -vf "crop={resolutions_crop[self.resolution]}" -c:v libx264 -qscale 0 -crf 0 -c:a copy result1.mp4`

**Добавление поверх видео пнг:** `ffmpeg -i result1.mp4 -i HTML/noback.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=0:0" -qscale 0 -c:a copy result/output1.mp4`

Все делается через `subprocess.call()` в питоне

Comment: А вопрос в чём? Знаете такое есть изречение, правильно заданный вопрос - уже половина ответа.

Comment: На вашем месте я бы  1) привёл видео файлы до и после обработки, и конкретно задал критерии для выходного видео "на глаз" или используется ПО для оределения качества? У вас речь идёт о кропе или о добавлении маски на видео? Это уже несколько разных тем.

Comment: Ещё нужно предоставить минимальный-воспроизводимый пример, раз речь идёт о скрипте на пайтон.